# What type of insulation can I use to insulate around my furnace exhaust?

Tags: insulation

I've got a cold breeze blowing through my basement, originating from where the furnace exhaust turns vertical. What type of insulation can I stuff in around the exhaust, to stop the cold air?

This exhaust is 5" rigid metallic duct that runs horizontal (with a slope) for 6', before turning vertical via an elbow and round to rectangular transition boot.

Comment: Asbestos works great! *snark*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Rockwool" or mineral fiber - looks sort of like fiberglass, but good for higher temperatures - most fiberglass is coated with a plastic product that smokes off (helps to bind the glass into a batt) otherwise I think fiberglass would be as effective, but given that (the plastic stuff smokes off) rockwool is the material of choice where you need high-heat resistance.

If the gap is very regular, there is a fiberglass product that would take the heat - stove gasketing - a rope-like product available in several sizes.

[image: Stove Gasket]

Comment: Roxul is the brand name of the mineral wool product that is easy recognizable among builders. It has been used for firestopping around chimneys. Their website has a demo showing its fire resistance. I do not work for this manufacturer, nor do I hold any interest of any other sort. The product just happens to be the one that was used by the construction company I worked for.

Comment: Mineral or rock fiber comes in several forms. It can be found in batts, panels, ropes, and inbedded in some high temp foams.